# Denoising kills it all

Tags: cycles-render-engine

I have been looking for some smart solution but after couple of hours I am done.

How can I save those grainy details, that in fact are noisy, from being smudged by denoiser? I am working with cycles, SID/Optix - same resultat.

For those renders I have been trying with super denoiser, set up pixel filter on 1.5, then 1.0, then 0.7, then 0.1 and 0.05 finally - it all ends up smudged and blurred, no matter of settings (SID - on the right[image], grainy texture - on the left).

Have been trying with 4k resolution and with super high sampling (like 3000), but it still gets blurred :/

Do you have any smart ideas of how to preserve textures like that? I mean, those based on noisy/musgrave procedural nodes. I am trying to improve my exterior archviz and those walls turns me mad, as they always end up plastic because of blured and ereased imprefections (like this grainy plaster).

My compositor (SID+color balance) and material(simple PBR + musgrave displacement):
[image]

Comment: It's tricky because a de-noiser's job is to reduce noise - which includes noisy textures sometimes. If worst comes to worst., you could do a couple of different render passes and stitch them together in the compositor. Use a Holdout node in place of your plaster texture (same material), and render. Then, disable or delete everything but the plaster, re-attach the texture (replace the holdout) and do another render on just those walls. Without the rest, you should be able to render with a sample count high enough that you don't need denoising, without _too_ severe performance issues.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'd like to see screenshots of your compositor node setup and your material setup if I may.  I think my answer addressed the wrong issue.  Are you're talking about the noise on the window glass, not the building, or both?  Do you want either?

Comment: @MartyFouts am gonna uptade post in a moment with my compositor setting and material, but compositor is based mainly on what SID has to offer.  Material on the other hand is basic PBR texture (just a color + sliders) with musgrave node pluged as displacment map. 

/ChristopherBennett I am pretty bad into render passes, truly speaking I am barely making my first steps into operating them. As much as I do understand the way of doing that you have described to me, ain't there anything simplier?